# How to ban a user temporarily in Meteor

Tags: meteor, temporary, meteor-useraccounts

I'm developing a simple application using Meteor to learn the framework. I'm using the `accounts-password` package which incorporates the `accounts-base` package.

User's will create an account and their email address will serve as their username for login in. This all works perfectly fine as intended. Now I want to take this to the next level.

I want to have the ability to temporarily ban a user for a temporary set period of time - let's say a week.

Is this functionality possible using the `accounts-password` package or is there another package that exists which will accomplish this functionality? Otherwise how can I implement this functionality on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using something like isBanned flag in the users collection against each user? That way, you check for this flag before logging the user in. You could further extend this by having a date field when the ban was applied and later have a way to calculate the elapsed time to see if the ban can be auto-lifted.

```
db.users.findOne()
{
    [...]
    "username" : "superadmin",
    "profile" : {
        "isActive" : true,
        "createdBy" : "system",

        // is this user banned? 
        "isBanned" : false,

        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-10-07T17:33:42.773Z"),
        "loginTime" : ISODate("2016-10-07T17:25:44.068Z"),
        "logoutTime" : ISODate("2016-10-07T17:33:42.660Z")
    },
    "roles" : [
        "superAdmin"
    ]
}
```

Your login form events could be like:

```
Template.loginForm.events({

    'submit #login-form': function(event,template){
        event.preventDefault();

// Check for isBanned flag

if(Meteor.users.find({username: template.find("#userName").value,isBanned: false}) {
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(
            template.find("#userName").value,
            template.find("#password").value,
            function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    // Display the login error to the user however you want
                    console.log("Error logging in. Error is: " + error);
                    Session.set('loginErrorMessage', error.message);
                    Router.go('/');
                }
            }
        );
        Meteor.call('updateLoginTime');
        Router.go('loggedIn');
    },
}
```

Comment: I like that idea, although the flag probably shouldn't sit inside the profile field because that is editable by the user client side.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle - Curious, how though? I'm also fairly new to meteor and hence don't know the entirety of such a security hole.

Comment: You can read all about it here in the official docs: https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#dont-use-profile

Comment: Thanks for this. After reading through the list of relevant links pertaining to this, I sure am smack in the center of noob meteor developers. Back to topic, (a) deny update on Meteor.users (b)  maintaining a separate collection with the user profile data not do the trick?

Comment: Don't worry, I'm still pretty noob at all this as well ;)  Yeah this certainly has helped me out a lot in figuring out how to tackle this issue, thanks!.

Comment: Thing is, if you are only checking this on the client side, a knowledgeable user can override it quite easily. This should be enforced on the server side. You can either prevent the user from logging in or allow log-ins and restrict activity. See [validateLoginAttempt](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-validateLoginAttempt) for ideas.